# Deep copy from a void pointer to a structure to another variable

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, deep-copy

I have a structure of the following type:

```
struct SPacket
{
    unsigned char payload[260]; 
    unsigned int payloadLength; 
};
```

I am using observer patterns to fire some events from one class in C++ and catch these events in another class along with some data. The aData is a void pointer to the above structure and the observer class function is something like;

```
void process(void* evt, void* aData)
{
    SPacket aPkt;
    // here I want to copy the content pointed by aData into aPkt 
    ..........
    .............     

}
```

May be its a silly question but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to say:

```
SPacket aPkt = *static_cast<SPacket*>(aData);
```